# Angular Forms: Provider/Setting for setting updateOn app-wide

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have been looking for a way to modify Angular Reactive Forms so that all form fields use an `updateOn` value which we specify (`onSubmit`). The only way I see so far is to set it per-formControl. That however is not scalable and we want to avoid another extra class for this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the `updateOn` property on the root `FormGroup`? All its `AbstractControl` children should [inherit that property](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/model.ts#L339-L341):

```js
 get updateOn(): FormHooks {
    return this._updateOn ? this._updateOn : (this.parent ? this.parent.updateOn : 'change');
  }
```

Comment: Well in our case we would like to have a way to set the default value for all formGroups. We have a lot of forms and would have liked to configure them all at once. The only way I found was to override the updateOn value in the AbstractControl prototype but that's nothing that would make it into production.

Comment: Makes sense now. I’m not aware of any way to configure it _globally_.